# Parse Jsvalue using scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing

I'm new at scala. I have a Json File that I rea it into String. Then I'm parsing the string to a JSValue. Now I'm trying to read all values to update my database, but i don't know how to proceed.

```
val l = scala.io.Source.fromFile("list.json").getLines().mkString
val result: JsValue = Json.parse(l)
```

My Json is like :

```
{
    picture_id : xxx
    width : xxx
    height : xxx
},
{
    picture_id : xxx
    width : xxx
    height : xxx
},
```

....

I want to extract even block to update database with right values.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like below. I hope the comments are explanatory:

```
val l = scala.io.Source.fromFile("list.json").getLines().mkString
val result: JsValue = Json.parse(l)

//Create a model to hold your json objects
case class Pic(id: String, width: String, height: String)

//Create a reader that reads your json string to your model(Pic)
implicit val picReads: Reads[Pic] = (
  (JsPath \ "picture_id").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "width").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "height").read[String] and
  )(Pic.apply _)

result.validate[List[Pic]] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[List[Pic]] => 
    //Deal with your list of pics here
  case e: JsError => println("Errors: " + JsError.toFlatJson(e).toString())
}
```